# Is this the right approach to create a component?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I made a view to show some contact information for the user:

```html
<template>
  <div v-for="user in users" class="user">
    <div class="userInformation">
      <img :src="user.photo" />
      <div class="userName">
        <h3>{{ user.age }}</h3>
        <p>{{ user.gender }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="button-wrapper">
      <a href="#">
        <button @click="$router.push(`/user/${user.id}`)">User Profile</button>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<style>
</style>
```

***users*** is an array that holds all users which I fetch from the backend.

I want to create a **component** so that I can re-use the user card in other classes and don´t have to include the markup. I tried it the following way but I'm stuck at the **button** to redirect the user and the **img** because I don´t know how to use **named slots** there.

```html
<template>
  <div class="user">
    <div class="userInformation">
      <img />
      <div class="userName">
        <h3>{{ age }}</h3>
        <p>{{ gender }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="button-wrapper">
      <a href="#">
        <button>User Profile</button>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "UserCard",
  props: [
    "age", 
    "gender"
  ]
};
</script>
```

Another problem is that I have to re-create the fetch method for my **users** in other classes to access the user information. Would there be a better way of doing this?

```html
// fetch user data from backend and create users array
...

<div v-for="user in users" :key="user.name">
   <UserCard 
     :age="`${user.age}`"
     :gender="`${user.gender}`"
   />
</div>
```

Is this the right approach to create a reusable component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're headed in the right direction for your component.  If you wanted a named slot for the button you could use something like this.

Child Component

```html
<template>
  ...
    
  <slot name="button">
    <!-- default/fallback content can be provided, if the parent does 
         not provide slot content the button-wrapper div will appear -->
    <div class="button-wrapper">
      <a href="#">
        <button>Default Button</button>
      </a>
    </div>
  </slot>
    
  </div>
</template>
```

Parent

```html
<div v-for="user in users" :key="user.name">
   <UserCard 
     :age="user.age"
     :gender="user.gender">
     <template v-slot:button>
       <div>some custom button here {{ user.phone }}</div>
     </template>
   </UserCard>
</div>
```

Also [compilation scope](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Compilation-Scope) (Vuejs v2 guide) is an important thing to keep in mind with slots - "Everything in the parent template is compiled in parent scope; everything in the child template is compiled in the child scope."

In terms of fetching your users, that's a separate issue.  Look into something like [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) or other ways of [managing shared state](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html) if you find yourself constantly having to fetch users in various components

Comment: Nice catch with the buttons. I used **$emit('doSomething'')"** and it works as well